# makefile modification time trickery?

Tags: makefile

So I have a makefile, and in that makefile is a rule that first performs a precompile transform and modifies the source file and then compiles it into the proper target.  I would like to know if there is a way to trick/coerce make into thinking that the source was not actually modified, so that make will only recompile when a user modifies, not when the make rule modifies the source.  I attempted to use the `touch` command to turn back the modification timestamp after the make modification, but without success.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it possible for you to add another rule in the same makefile that does not change your source files? Can you paste a piece of your makefile with the rule you mention?

Comment: Under what circumstances should Make run the transform and thereby modify the source file?

Comment: @Beta - make should perform the transform any time that it sees that the source has changed and needs to be recompiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way to accomplish what you want is to create a *secondary target* -- that is a zero length file which acts like a flag to say whether you've done what you want to do or not, and have the rule which does the precompile transform based on that file.

I guess I have a question about what you are trying to do. Why do the transform *in-place*, rather than have the transform create an intermediate file which then gets compiled.

In-place transformations can be problematic, especially if the transform process is not idempotent.

**Edit 1**

Based on your question, I would say you could do this:

```
target.flag: target.original-file
    touch target.save -r target.original-file
    <do transformation>
    touch target.original-file -r target.save
    rm target.save
    touch target.flag
```

Using touch with the "-r" option says to grab the access date from the specified file. So you would be saving the date of the original file on temporary file. Then do the transformation, then use touch to grab the date from the temporary file and put it back on the *now transformed* file.

Comment: Or you could switch to ANT, which is a little more elegant and powerful than Make. Make is kind of like stone knives and bear skins compared to some newer tools.

Comment: And how would you do it in Ant?

Comment: The transform has to be performed in place, as it is a band-aid to a 3rd party tool I'm using that has a bug, and the transform is actually used to modify the source before it is checked back into source control. BTW, the transform is idempotent.

Comment: Ant would be a nice alternative if I wasn't maintaining legacy code. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
foo.target: foo.source
    $(TRANSFORM) $<
    $(COMPILE) $<
```